# Flowcharts to help selecting the proper analysis technique and test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-mining, exploratory-data-analysis

As someone who needs statistical knowledge but is not a formally trained statistician, I'd find it helpful to have a flowchart (or some kind of decision tree) to help me choose the correct approach to solve a particular problem (eg. "do you need this and know that and that and consider data to be normally distributed? Use technique X. If data is not normal, use Y or Z").

After some [googling](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&q=flowchart+to+select+statistical+test), I've seen several attempts of various coverage and quality (some not available at the moment). I've also seen similar flowcharts in statistics textbooks I've consulted in libraries.

A bonus would be an interactive site that, besides just having a chart, would provide extra info (such as assumptions) and would point to how to perform those techniques in popular stat packages. "Need to do ANOVA in R? You need package X and here's a tutorial".

I'm asking as a community wiki question in the hope there are better resources I couldn't find. Since statistics is a large subject, I think such a flowchart would be suitable for techniques that can be approached by someone who has beginner or intermediate-level knowledge. Anything more complicated would need someone with formal training.

Answer (score 10):

These are not really interactive flowcharts, but maybe this could be useful: (1) http://j.mp/cmakYq, (2) http://j.mp/aaxUsz, and (3) http://j.mp/bDMyAR.

Comment: Not bad at all. The format is static, but the information is very useful.

Comment: @chl Maybe you should consider pasting them into your answer and providing reference for them?

Answer (score 5):

You can look at the solution given on the question ["Statistical models cheat sheet"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/statistical-models-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 2):

I have made this https://www.statsflowchart.co.uk, an interactive stats test flowchart. Let me know what you think. (This is based on an Andy Field flowchart from a text-book, linked on the site).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning in your answer that this is based on the flowchart put together by Field (presumably in one of his statistics for psychology books?)

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: Hi, Thanks for highlighting. It has now moved to a dedicated URL: http://www.statsflowchart.co.uk